# How to apply several side images to WPF 3D model?

Tags: wpf, 3d

I have already a 3D model for a planet and 4 pictures of front (0 degree), left (270), right (90) and back (180) side of the planet. Is there any known way to apply these 4 photos for texture of the 3D model?

I thought about combining these pictures into one like panoramic view and then apply it to the model. But that might be overkill. Maybe there is a way to apply 2D texture to the 2D view of 3D model like WYSWYG. Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be to combine the images into a single rectangular projection and then map that to the sphere using a spherical mapping.

Assuming your images are circular the first step is to create square images from those. A Mercator projection will probably work best.